# Postgresql, define box variable in function

Tags: postgresql, function

I am trying to define a box variable in a PostgreSQL function. Here is an arbitrary function that I've tried and it does not work:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "public"."find_centroid"("argbase_x" int8, "argbase_y" int8, "arg_length" int)
  RETURNS TABLE("cent_x" float8, "cent_y" float8) AS $BODY$
    DECLARE
    edge_x int8;
    edge_y int8;
    bounds text;
BEGIN
    edge_x := "argbase_x" + 5;
    edge_y := "argbase_y" + 5;  
    RETURN QUERY
    SELECT sum(location[0])/count("location") as cent_x, sum(location[1])/count("location") as cent_y 
from points
WHERE "location" <@ box'(("argbase_x","argbase_y"),("argbase_x"+"arg_length","argbase_y"+"arg_length"))';

END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100
```

The issue is with how to build a box from arguments `box'(("argbase_x","argbase_y"),("argbase_x"+"arg_length","argbase_y"+"arg_length"))'`

I've tried various methods so far, like string concatenation for example. But nothing is working and I can't seem to find any resources online that offers an example on how to declare or define a geometric variable in a function.

Comment: Why re-invent the wheel? I would guess that PostGIS offers functions like that as well (and most probably a much faster implementation as well)

Comment: I can't install PostGIS I'm afraid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several trials and errors. This worked for me:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "public"."find_centroid"("argbase_x" int8, "argbase_y" int8, "arg_length" int)
  RETURNS TABLE("cent_x" float8, "cent_y" float8) AS $BODY$
    DECLARE
    edge_x int8;
    edge_y int8;
    bounds text;
BEGIN
    edge_x := "argbase_x" + 5;
    edge_y := "argbase_y" + 5; 
    bounds := CONCAT('((',"argbase_x"::text,',',"argbase_y"::text,'), 
    RETURN QUERY
    SELECT sum(location[0])/count("location") as cent_x, sum(location[1])/count("location") as cent_y 
from points
WHERE "location" <@ box(bounds);

END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100
```

Answer (score -1):

you don't have to define any special "box variable", bounding box is done simply as `x BETWEEN min_x AND max_x AND y BETWEEN min_y AND max_y`

if I understood the logic of the function correctly it would be

```
WHERE location[0] BETWEEN "argbase_x" AND "argbase_x"+"arg_length"
AND location[1] BETWEEN "argbase_y" AND "argbase_y"+"arg_length"
```

for more complex shapes there are no built-in operators in Postgres. You'll have to use [WKT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text_representation_of_geometry) notation to construct your shapes and PostGIS functions to convert WKT to geometry type [here](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeomFromText.html) and identify [containment](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Contains.html) or [intersection](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Intersects.html).

Comment: The function I provided is just a mere example to calculate the centroid. The fact is my actual function requires declaring several geometric shapes.